# Images sizes Distribution

Tags: matlab

I have a set of images with different sizes. I would like to plot a image size distribution. How? Thanks.

I know we can get image size from:

[row, col] = size(imageNo);

Comment: You can accumulate the sizes into a vector and use `hist` to get a histogram of the sizes. By the way, take in account that if your image is a color image you must use `[row, col, nchannels] = size(imageNo);` otherwise col will be the product of the number of columns and channels.

Comment: Try [`histogram`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html).